# Applescript error -10000 when saving Mail attachments in Mojave 10.4.6

Tags: applescript, error

My script for the Mail app saves attachments from each message. It was working fine and suddenly started generating this error in macOS 10.14.6 Mojave:

```
--> error "To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info." number -10000
```

The script line that resulted in this error was:

```
save mail attachment id "2" of message id 33167 of mailbox "Trash Later" in "/Volumes/Backup/email attachments/ATT00001.jpg"
```

I tried changing the permissions of the target folder using "chmod 775" but no luck.
Apple's documentation has this cryptic description of the error:

```
-10000 The Apple event handler failed.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Following a hunch that it had to do with the steadily increasing new permissions requests, I **added the "Script Editor" app** to this preference:
**System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Full Disk Access**

The error -10000 disappeared and the script is back to saving attachments.
I'll update if the error returns.